# Inequality. $\sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{a+b+\sqrt{2a+2c}})^3 \le \frac{8}{9}$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Problem. When $a, b, c>0, a, b, c \in \Bbb R, 16(a+b+c)\ge\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$, Prove that

$$\sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{a+b+\sqrt{2a+2c}})^3 \le \frac{8}{9}$$

My approach: If we let $x=a+b, y=b+c, z=c+a$, we can know that
$$4(x+y+z) \ge -2\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2yz-2zx}{(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)}$$

And the inequality that I have to prove will be:
$$\sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2y}})^3 \le \frac{8}{9}$$

But I cannot think further. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  We look for more information in posts here than some other sites - in particular, please include the source of problems like this as well as some motivation for them, whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{x}{4},$ $b=\frac{y}{4}$ and $c=\frac{z}{4}.$

Thus, the condition gives $$x+y+z\geq\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$ or
$$1\leq\frac{xyz(x+y+z)}{xy+xz+yz}$$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\left(x+y+2\sqrt{2(x+z)}\right)^3}\leq\frac{1}{72}.$$
Now, by AM-GM
$$\left(x+y+2\sqrt{2(x+z)}\right)^3\geq\left(3\sqrt[3]{(x+y)\left(\sqrt{2(x+z)}\right)^2}\right)^3=54(x+y)(x+z).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(x+z)(y+z)}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$8(x+y+z)\leq3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z),$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$8(x+y+z)\cdot\frac{xyz(x+y+z)}{xy+xz+yz}\leq3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z),$$ or
$$3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)(xy+xz+yz)\geq8xyz(x+y+z)^2.$$
Now, since $$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq\frac{8}{9}(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{8}{9}(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)\cdot3(xy+xz+yz)\geq8xyz(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$(xy+xz+yz)^2\geq3xyz(x+y+z).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Of course. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @coding1101 You are welcome!